# why does this c program print twice

Tags: c, stdout

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char c = 'A';
        while (c != ',')
        {
                printf("Input a character:");
                scanf("%c", &c);
                if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                {
                        printf("%d\n", (int)c);
                }
        }
}
```

After taking in the first set of input, this code prints out "Input a character" twice each time - why is this?

Comment: Insert a blank before %  scanf(" %c", &c); Otherwise the new line character that corresponds to the key Enter is also read

Comment: It read the character, writes the prompt, it reads a newline, writes the prompt.

Comment: I'm 100% sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find of what.

Comment: When you press the `Enter` key a `'\n'` is generated in the *Input buffer* (e.g. `stdin`). You read 1-char, leaving the `'\n'` in `stdin` to be read on the next iteration of the `while` loop. Including a `space` in your *format string* (before the `%c` *format specifier*) causes `scanf` to skip all intervening *whitespace* (`'\n'` being whitepace). This is one of the *primary pitfalls* C-programmers fall victim to using `scanf` for user input, and why `fgets` is the recommended way to take user input.

Comment: "prints out "Input a character" twice each time" is because user typed 2 keys.

Answer (score 1):

cause you press a number PLUS enter and enter will be read by `scanf()` at the next call

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char c = 'A';
  while (c != ',') {
    printf("Input a character:");
    if (scanf("%c", &c) != 1) {
      return 0; // we stop if user don't input anything
    }
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
      printf("%d\n", (int)c); // by the way did you want (int)(c - '0') ?
    } else {
      printf("enter a number ! you enter %d\n", c);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A space before `%c` should be enough =>> `" %c"`